# XCM TransferAsset from one account to another account on Rococo doesn't work

Tags: xcm

I am testing some things out with XCM and I want to make a ROC token transfer from one Rococo account to another Rococo account using XCM. I am calling the `execute` extrinsic and providing the `TransferAsset` XCM message.

For some reason, the transfer doesn't occur, but the status of the extrinsic is successful: https://rococo.subscan.io/extrinsic/6027042-2

To be more specific, the exact problem I have is that the ROC tokens don't get transferred from one account to the other one.

Comment: I'm a newbie to learn XCM Message, can you give me the script code for reference? Thank you.

Comment: @DungNguyen Sure, the code is actually part of a project I am working on. You can view all the XCM code [here](https://github.com/TheDotflow/dotflow-ui/tree/main/src/utils/transactionRouter). It contains native transfers, teleportation, and all the possible kinds of reserve transfers.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will follow this repo. Good luck to you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your reftime is specified as 0, which is not enough, it will cause `WeightLimitReached` error, you can try to specify reftime as `3000000000`

This is my test record: https://rococo.subscan.io/extrinsic/6078033-2

Comment: I thought leaving it at zero meant 'unlimited'. It seems like I was wrong :)